# Too many GRPC calls for create snapshot

Tags: kubernetes, grpc-go, csi-driver, kubernetes-csi

In our CSI Driver, we recently included snapshot feature support. Using v6.0.1 external-snapshotter. I see that when we do a create snapshot action, too many GRPC calls are seen in the logs for `csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot`

```
cat driver.log | grep 'csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot' 
I0927 17:47:14.105028       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:17.243862       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:18.155425       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:19.026359       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:19.816381       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:20.553471       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:21.265841       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:22.090815       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:22.851513       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:23.555432       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:24.269332       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:25.051528       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:25.764960       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:26.682565       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:27.359656       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:28.120403       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:28.790861       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:29.509234       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:30.199635       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:30.905746       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:31.605362       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:32.418714       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:33.306218       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:34.021675       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:34.754203       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:35.593932       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:38.163890       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:38.958784       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:39.901797       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:40.594249       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:41.351820       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:42.071174       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
I0927 17:47:42.765785       1 server.go:151] GRPC call: /csi.v1.Controller/CreateSnapshot
```

What could possibly be the reason. Any pointers on where I should start looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could log the addresses of the clients. In Go, you can get their addresses with [`peer.FromContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.49.0/peer#FromContext). This would help you determine whether you have too many callers operating simultaneously or if you have a single misconfigured caller.